# How to combine values inside two parenthesis into one inside a string in python?

Tags: python

I have a string,I want to convert

```
  '{"Name":"Tom", "Age:20}, {"Name":"Tina", "Age:19}' into one 
  '{"Name":"Tom","Age":20,"Name":"Tina"Age:19}'
```

I tried by replacing parenthesis with space and then add it again in starting and end of the string.
How do I do it in single line? Kindly help.

Comment: Parse it first and then use `{**dict1, **dict2}` don't use strings.

Comment: @Countour-Integral `dict`s cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: How did you end up with that string in the first place?

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta You can still use `collections.defaultdict` after you've parsed it

Comment: @Countour-Integral doesn't matter what you use, you can't have two `'Age'` keys. Unless of course you are talking about nested nested dicts.

Comment: use this if you want the final output to be string: `x = '{' + x.replace('{', "").replace('}', "") + '}'`

Comment: this requirement is odd, you can use "name1", "name2" to the tag instead of this

Comment: `"Age` is missing an enclosing quote `"`. How did you get this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.partition', but this assumes you know the exact separator and you only have two parts to join:

```
>>> part1, sep, part2 = '{"Name":"Tom", "Age:20}, {"Name":"Tina", "Age:19}'.partition('}, {')
>>> ', '.join([part1, part2])
'{"Name":"Tom", "Age:20, "Name":"Tina", "Age:19}'
```

For multiple parts, use `str.split`:

```
>>> s = '{"Name":"Tom", "Age":20}, {"Name":"Tina", "Age":19}, {"Name":"John", "Age":19}'
', '.join(s.split('}, {'))
Out[29]: '{"Name":"Tom", "Age":20, "Name":"Tina", "Age":19, "Name":"John", "Age":19}'
>>> ', '.join(s.split('}, {'))
```

Or simply `str.replace`:

```
>>> '{"Name":"Tom", "Age:20}, {"Name":"Tina", "Age:19}'.replace('}, {', ', ')
'{"Name":"Tom", "Age:20, "Name":"Tina", "Age:19}'
```

Comment: `replace` and `partition` will cause problems if there is `}, {` inside quotes.

Comment: @Countour-Integral, you can't parse json without ... json parser